# Strip non ascii chars but allow currency symbols

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, currency

I am using below regex to strip all non-ascii characters from a string.

```
String pattern = @"[^\u0000-\u007F]";
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
rx.Replace(data," ");
```

However, i want to allow use of curreny (pound symbol) and trademark symbols.

I have modified above regex as shown below & it works for me. Can anyone just confirm if the regex is valid ?

```
 String pattern = @"[^\u0000-\u007F \p{Sc}]";
```

**Basically, I want to allow all currency symbols too.**

Comment: Everytime I'm going to answer, you edit the question :P

Comment: Sorry. Done with editing :)

Comment: Yes, your regex is correct. It will match anything except the range you specified (`0000-007F`) or currency symbol characters. See the meaning of `\p{Sc}`: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop

Comment: Cool..now if i further want to add support for trademark or copyright symbol then is the below pattern correct ?

String pattern = @"[^\u0000-\u007F \p{Sc} \u00A9 \u2122]";

Inshort, i just need to keep on adding \xxxx ..right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, your regex is correct.**

What you are doing with your code is replacing the characters matched by your regular expressions by an empty character.

Now, what characters does your regular expression match?

Anything except:

- The range you specified: `0000-007F`
- Currency symbol characters: `\p{Sc}`. See http://regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop

If you just want to keep allowing some other characters, yes, you can add them too (exactly like you did with `\p{Sc}`.

**Edit:**

Be careful when doing it in the future. The regex would really be `[^\u0000-\u007F\p{Sc}]` (no space), although in this case it doesn't matter since the space character was already in the ASCII range.